# Representing first order sentences as conceptual graphs

Tags: logic, formal-systems

Here are three first order axioms that represents a part of a [mereology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/) theory.

**Reflexivity** $\forall x : part(x,x)$

**Antisymmetry** $\forall x  \forall y : ((part(x,y) \land part(y,x)) \implies (x = y))$

**Transitivity**  $\forall x  \forall y \forall z :((part(x,y) \land part(y,z))  \implies part(x,z))$

Here is my attempt to present these axioms as a set of [conceptual graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_graph) (CG). [CGs](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.460.8912&rep=rep1&type=pdf) can be represented in [Common Logic](http://www.jfsowa.com/talks/clintro.pdf) [(ISO zipped PDF)](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c066249_ISO_IEC_24707_2018.zip).

[image]

My understanding of the above CG is as follows:

The variables are universally quantified.

The arrow on graph representing reflexivity is bi-directional.

Both antisymmetry and transitivity are represented by an IF-THEN contexts.

The three graphs are all related by conjunction.

Dotted lines are co-references.

Equality (=) is actually commutative, but is represented as a directed relation .

**Question:**

Is my attempt at representing the FOL sentence as CG's reasonable? How could my representation be improved?

This questions spans logic and knowledge representation so it may not be a good fit for a mathematics forum. Perhaps someone could suggest a more appropriate forum for questions such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know about the technical details of Conceptual Graphs, but I do know that it is based off Existential Graphs, and here are the respective representations in Existential Graphs:

$\forall x \ part(x,x)$:

[image]

$\forall x \forall y \ ((part(x,y) \land part(y,x)) \to x = y)$:
[image]

$\forall x \forall y \forall z \ ((part(x,y) \land part(y,z)) \to part(x,z))$:

[image]

The last two certainly look like what you have!